# On the sequence of function $f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Is the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n $ uniformly convergent over $[0,1]$ ? Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ convergent with $0<x<1$ ? Is the series uniformly convergent with $0<x<1$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? You should find the maximum of $f_n$ for all $n$ to solve this problem.

Comment: Try to find the pointwise limit first. It should be easy. If it exists (denote it by $f$), check if $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @luka5z: pointwise limit is $0$ - function ... I am actually more interested in the series ...

Comment: @luka5z: umm , I don't think so ... it is not uniform ... take the sequence $x_n=1/{\sqrt n}$ to see it ..

Comment: The series is on the form $\sum n^2 r^n$ so it is basically just the second derivative of the geometrical series $\sum r^n$. This can be evaluated to give $s(x) = \frac{x^4 - 3x^2 + 2}{x^5}$ and we see that $x=0$ is a singular point (which is not surprising since $\lim f_n(1/\sqrt{n}) \to \infty$).

Answer (score 3):

$f_{n}(x)\leq n^{2}(1-x^{2})^{n}$ on $I$ so the pointwise limit is $0$.

$f'_{n}(x)=n^{2}\left [ (1-x^{2})^{n}-2nx^{2}(1-x^{2})^{n-1} \right ]$ and so $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ is the maximum on $I$. At this point, $\overline x_{n}$ we have

$f_{n}(\overline x_{n})=n^{2}\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt {2n+1}} \right )\left ( \frac{2n}{2n+1} \right )^{n}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty $ so $f_{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $I$.

Now, if $x=0$ or $x=1$ the series obviously converges to $0$. On the other hand, if $x\in (0,1)$ and $c=1-x^{2}$ then $f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x^2)^n\leq \frac{n^{2}}{c^{n}}$ so the series converges pointwise to an $F\in \mathbb R^{I}$.

The convergence is not uniform on $(0,1)$however:

We have that

$F_{N}(x)=x\sum_{n=0}^{N}n^{2}(1-x^{2})^{n}>x\sum_{n=0}^{N}(1-x^{2})^{n}$ and since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(1-x^{2})^{n}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ we see that $$\tag1F(x)>\frac{1}{x}$$

Now fix $N$, let $x_{max}$ be the value of $x\in (0,1)$ such that $F_{N}(x_{max})>F_{N}(x), \forall x\in (0,1)$. Then appealing to $(1)$ we may choose $x\in (0,1)$ such that

$F(x)-F_{N}(x_{max})>1$

which implies that

$F(x)-F_{N}(x)>1$

So we have found, for each $N$, an $x$ for which $F(x)-F_{N}(x)>1$ and so $\left \{ F_{N} \right \}_{N}$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: The question was whether the series converged uniformly on $(0,1),$ not on $[0,1).$

Comment: @zhw. yes I misread the problem. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed $0<x<1$, the series is convergent by the Ratio Test.  However, the series does not converge uniformly.  Its value  $S(x)$ satisfies $S(x)\geq x\sum (1-x^2)^n=x/x^2=1/x$, which is unbounded on $(0,1)$.  So, for any partial sum $S_N(x)$, there will always be some $0<x<1$ with $S(x)\geq1/x>S_N(x)+1$. So the convergence is not uniform.